# RESTful API controller/route issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

With VS 2013 I created a simple MVC/Web Api app. It has Photo model:

```
public class Photo
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeOriginal { get; set; }
}
```

and a PhotoController:

```
Photo[] photos = new Photo[] 
{ 
    new Photo { Id= 1, Name= "Mary B.",  DateTimeOriginal = Convert.ToDateTime("May 18, 2015 2:01:22 PM")}, 
    new Photo { Id = 2, Name= "Martin M.",  DateTimeOriginal = Convert.ToDateTime("May 18, 2015 2:13:09 PM" )}, 
    new Photo { Id = 3, Name= "Sparky",  DateTimeOriginal = Convert.ToDateTime("May 18, 2015 2:31:22 PM")} 
};


public IEnumerable<Photo> GetAllPhotos()
{
    return photos;
}

public IHttpActionResult GetPhoto(int id)
{
    var photo = photos.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (photo == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(photo);
}

public IHttpActionResult GetPhoto(string Name)
{
    var photo = photos.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name== Name);
    if (photo == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}

//I added this to see if this helps with the routing. It didn't
public IHttpActionResult GetName(string Name)
{
    var photo = photos.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name== Name);
    if (photo == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(photo);

}
```

This compiles and I can issue a web request like this:

```
http://localhost:59628/api/photos
```

And I'll get back an array of photo elements.

I can issue a web request like this:

```
http://localhost:59628/api/photos/2
```

And I'll get back element where ID =2

But

```
http://localhost:59628/api/photos/"Mary B"
```

or

```
Name="Mary B"
```

or

```
/GET/Name/Mary B
```

or

```
/api/photos/name/Mary B
```

it returns an error.

SO my first question is why? How can I query the service for photos by name?

Second question: I see the information in the route config but even when I add this to the PhotosController:

```
[Route("photos/{photo}/Name")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetName(string Name)
{
    var photo = photos.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name== Name);
    if (photo == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(photo);
}
```

I get back a 404. WHY?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: Look at your `WebApiConfig.cs` file. What do you notice about the route(s)?

Comment: I see config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Thank for that link. I should study it for a while. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are configured so that the api knows how to handle requests for resources.

`404 Not Found` is returned when the api cannot find the resource that was requested based on configuration.

If planning to use attribute routing, make sure to configure it in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file like

```
// Attribute routing.
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

// Convention-based routing.
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

For attribute routing the `PhotosController` would then need to be updated

```
[RoutePrefix("api/photos")]
public class PhotosController : ApiController {

    Photo[] photos = new Photo[] 
    { 
        new Photo { Id= 1, Name= "Mary B",  DateTimeOriginal = Convert.ToDateTime("May 18, 2015 2:01:22 PM")}, 
        new Photo { Id = 2, Name= "Martin M",  DateTimeOriginal = Convert.ToDateTime("May 18, 2015 2:13:09 PM" )}, 
        new Photo { Id = 3, Name= "Sparky",  DateTimeOriginal = Convert.ToDateTime("May 18, 2015 2:31:22 PM")} 
    };

    //GET api/photos
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Photo> GetAllPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    //GET api/photos/5
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPhoto(int id) {
        var photo = photos.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (photo == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(photo);
    }

    //GET api/photos/name/Mary B
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("name/{name}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPhotoByName(string name) {
        var photo = photos.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Name == name);
        if (photo == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(photo);
    }
}
```